# How to access modal pop up using Watir

Tags: html, popup, modal-dialog, watir

I am new to Watir and this is my first assignment. I have done a series of automation but got stuck at a point where I had to click a file upload button on a modal pop up. So basically I click on a html link which says restore

```
<a id="restore-link" class="open-modal" href="profiles/restore_form">
  Restore Profile
</a>
```

This works and opens a modal pop up window the code for which is attached below. I need to click on the file upload and set a path and click on the restore in the modal window. Any hints or suggestions? The code for the modal window that opens up are as shown below.

```
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
  <span id="ui-dialog-title-modal" class="ui-dialog-title">&nbsp;</span>
    <a role="button" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#">
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span>
    </a>
</div>
<div scrollleft="0" scrolltop="0" style="width: auto; min-height: 50px; height: auto;" id="modal" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
  <form id="restore-profile-form" action="profiles/restore" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-head">
        <h2>Restore Profile</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="form-body">
        <div class="form-field">
          <label for="name">Backup <em class="mandatory">*</em></label>
          <input id="backup" name="backup" type="file">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-foot">
        <input value="Restore" id="restore-profile-submit" type="submit">
        <a href="#" onclick="return closeModalWindow()" id="restore-profile-cancel">Cancel</a>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work

```rb
browser.a(:id => 'restore-link').click
browser.window(:index => 1).use # switch to new modal window

browser.file_field(:id => 'backup').set file_path
browser.button(:id => 'restore-profile-submit').click
browser.window(:index => 0).use # switch back
```

Answer (score 0):

This is different for watir and watir-webdriver 
using watir you can access a modal dialog by

`modal = browser.modal_dialog`

once you have your modal dialog you can do anything that you could normally do with a browser

`modal.file_field(:id => 'backup').set(file_path)`
`modal.button(:id => 'restore-profile-submit').click`

or
`modal.link(:text => 'Cancel').click`

using webdriver p0deje's comment should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to leave this as a comment but couldn't.

I order for my test to manipulate the pop-up modal, I had to change

```
browser.a(:id => 'restore-link').click
```

to

```
browser.a(:id => 'restore-link').click_no_wait
```

then I was able to verify the correct pop-up modal was called

```
browser.alert.text.include?("Invalid URL")
```

and acknowledge it

```
browser.alert.ok
```

You can find information on the "alert" methods at http://watirwebdriver.com/javascript-dialogs/